# Pythagorean Triples $\mod{c}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I have a quick question regarding modular arithmetic.

If I have a Pythagorean Triple $(a, b, c)$, is it possible to consider this equation $\mod{c}$. That is to say,

> Is the implication
>
> $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \implies (a \mod{c})^2 + (b \mod{c})^2 \equiv 0\mod{c}$$
>
> true?

I attempted to prove this (rather naïvely) by remembering that

\begin{align}
a + cx &= a \mod{c}\\
b + cy &= b \mod{c}\\
cz &= 0 \mod{c}
\end{align}

for some $x, y, z \in \Bbb{Z}.$ Squaring these expressions gives me

$$a^2 + b^2 + 2cx(a + b) + c^2(x^2 + y^2) = cz$$

and hence that $$a^2 + b^2 \equiv 0 \mod{c}.$$

Have I made some fundamental error or is this a valid method?

**Edit:** Changed $c^2z^2$ to $cz$.

Comment: You are right: From $a^2+b^2=c^2$, we caan conclude  immediately $a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod{c}$.

Comment: Oh of course, unnecessary proof. In that case, could it then be easier to check if a triple is pythagorean by looking at $a^2$ and $b^2$ modulo $c$ ?

Comment: If $a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod{c}$, it does not necessarily follow that $a^2+b^2=c^2$. But certainly if $a^2+b^2\not\equiv 0\pmod{c}$, then $(a,b,c)$ is not a triple. I do not know whether the test you suggest might speed up things in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be true due to
a mod b=a if a

Proof:
Since a and b are smaller than c,
$((a\mod c)^2+(b\mod c)^2)\mod c=(a^2+b^2)\mod c=c^2\mod c=0$

Q.E.D.

And yes, your method is valid too, it is just a longer version of the method above